# MongoDB connection causes System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a few web servers running the same asp.net mvc web application, connecting to one mongodb server. One web server keeps throwing SocketException, even I restart IIS. The others are working fine. This is not the first time of the exception. A few weeks ago a different web server had the same problem, while at that time others were working.The error message:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system
>   lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

now I can do nothing but restart the server to fix the issue temporarily. I make sure the dynamic port range of the web server is correctly set by modifying `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort` to 65534. Now I doubt if it's a bug of the C# mongodb driver. I looked into the source code of the driver, especially [MongoCursorEnumerator.cs](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCursorEnumerator.cs), where the connection is released. The class `MongoCursorEnumerator<TDocument>` implements `IDisposable` and it correctly releases the connection in its `Dispose` method. But it has no destructor(finalizer), which guarantees a call to `Dispose` in GC.

Now I make sure all connection-related codes are correctly wrapped in `using` blocks in the project. In this circumstance, can the lack of destructor/finalizer causes the SocketException? If not, what's the possible reason of this exception then?

More info: ASP.NET MVC 3, Windows Server 2008 R2, Mongo DB 2.0, Mongo Db Driver for C# 1.5

**UPDATE**

the latest version of mongo db C# driver resolves the issue

Comment: `MongoCursorEnumerator<T>` implements `IEnumerable`, which means that the compiler will emit a call to its dispose method in a finally block.  It shouldn't need a finalizer, assuming it's used in a foreach loop.  If the enumerator is used manually, then there's a chance that dispose won't be called.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens: I myself also think the dispose is guaranteed to be called. The exception is really weired.

Answer (score 0):

One cause for this error (which is coming straight from the Windows operating system) is when TCP/IP connections are rapidly opened and closed.

Are you calling Disconnect anywhere in your code? That would cause all sockets to be closed, which would then result in new ones being opened to replace them.

Comment: I get this error maybe 1% of the time (around 10 writes/sec) - is some try/catch/retry code common advice for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to mongodb driver to 2.12 or higher would allow you to catch this exception.